# How can I let my DropdownButton affect my TextFormField

Tags: flutter, provider, dropdownbutton, flutter-change-notifier, textformfield

I think this is probably not too complicated, but I am new to coding and don't understand this, nor could I find an explanation online that I could understand.

In my app my AppBar includes both a title and a bottom, the title has been just text, and the bottom was a TextFormField users used to search through my database.

Recently I updated the title to a DropdownButton, and I wanted to use what the user selected there to change the the search parameters in my TextFormField (so that it would search different columns in my database).

I built the DropdownButton in a separate document, and then inserted it into title. Finding how to use it has been more tricky.

I built some sort of callback, which worked to print in my console, but I couldn't figure out how to pass the information into my TextFormField.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  _handleValueReturned(value) {
    if (value == 1) {print('This works');} if (value == 2) {print('This works not');} else {return null;}
  }
```

...

```
appBar: AppBar(
      title: DropDownButton(
          valueReturned: _handleValueReturned,
      ),

      bottom:...
```

...

Do I have to use some sort of provider or "of" or packages like Eventifier or ChangeNotifier? I couldn't figure out how all these things worked.

Comment: It sounds like you need to either use a state management strategy like setState or Bloc to change things according to what option the user selects in the drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you are trying to set the selected value from the `DropDownButton` in the `TextFormField`, if that is what you are trying to do then create a `TextEditingController` and add it to the `TextFormField` then set its `text` property inside your callback which is called `_handleValueReturned`, but you have to rebuild the widget so the `TextFormField` is rebuilt with the new value, of course, you have to convert your widget into `StatefulWidget` to do that.

Creating and initializing the `TextEditingController`:

```
final _controller = TextEditingController();
```

Attatching the controller to the `TextFromField`:

```
TextFormField(
  controller: _controller,
  ...
);
```

Changing the value of the controller inside `_handleValueReturned` callback:

```
 _handleValueReturned(value) {
    ...
    setState((){
      _controller.text = value; // It can be any String according to your scenario.
    });
  }
```

> Side Note: When you are dealing with a simple text input such as one input field then you do not have to use `TextFormField` and you can simply replace it with `TextField`.

I hope I got your problem correctly and I hope it got fixed.

Comment: I guess I wasn't very clear. I was hoping to `child: TextFormField(  onChanged: (text) { if [some value based on drop down] then one query, else [another query].`

Comment: I'm sorry but I am still not able to get your idea.